# Equivalent definition of orthogonal support projections

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]

The above sreentshot is from Takesaki's book.

I have three questions

(1).how to get $\|\varphi_{+}\|=\langle s(\varphi_{+}), \varphi\rangle$?

(2) How to conclude that $\|\varphi_{+}\|=\langle s(\varphi_{+}), \varphi_1\rangle$?

(3)How to verify that $s(\varphi_1)\leq s(\varphi_{+})$?

$s()$ denote by the support projection of a normal positive linear functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The functional $\varphi_+$ is positive, so (since $s(\varphi_+)\leq e$ and so $f\,s(\varphi_+)=0$),  $$\|\varphi_+\|=\varphi_+(1)=\varphi_+(s(\varphi_+))=\varphi(e\,s(\varphi_+))=\varphi(e\,s(\varphi_+)-f\,s(\varphi_+))=\varphi(s(\varphi_+)).$$
2. You have that $\|\varphi_+\|\leq\|\varphi_1\|$, $\|\varphi_-\|\leq\|\varphi_2\|$, and $\|\varphi_+\|+\|\varphi_-\|=\|\varphi_1\|+\|\varphi_2\|$.
3. From$\varphi_1(s(\varphi_+))=\|\varphi_1\|$. As $s(\varphi_1)$ is the smallest projection $p$ with $\|\varphi_1\|=\|\varphi(p)\|$, you get that $s(\varphi_1)\leq s(\varphi_+)$.

Comment: What is $e$? Is it the support projection of $\varphi_{+}$? I don't understand why $\varphi(e)=\varphi_{+}(e)$. If we have the Jordan decomposition, we have $\varphi=\varphi_{+}-\varphi_{-}$, how to conclude that $\varphi_{-}(e)=0$?

Comment: "$e$", as in **two** lines above the image you posted, in the proof you are reading. You have $\varphi_-(e)=0$ by definition, since $\varphi_-(e)=\varphi(fe)=0$. I clarified a bit in 1.